# How to differentiate SVC HP & BP?

Tags: h.264, svc

Like we can read H264 m line in SDP and confirm whether its H264 BP or HP, is there a way to differentiate SVC HP and BP by looking at SDP information?

SVC line:

```
a=rtpmap:122 X-H264UC/90000
a=fmtp:122 packetization-mode=1;mst-mode=NI-TC
```

H264 line:

```
a=fmtp:100 profile-level-id=640029; 
packetization-mode=1;
max-mbps=245760; max-fs=8196
```

Answer (score 1):

`H264UC` (Unified Communications) is a Microsoft specific H.264 SVC implementation.

The `packetization-mode` in the SDP corresponds to a UCConfig mode. For example `1` means `H.264 UCConfig Mode 1` which conforms to the UC Constrained High toolset.

I am not familiar with the Microsoft implementation but as far as I can tell these are subsets of ITU-T H.264 profiles / scalable profiles.

This [document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/F/B/AFBF8CBE-3A45-472A-93F3-AD8521FBD502/UC_Specification_for_H264_AVC_and_SVC_encoder.pdf) might help you.